# Cannot access @ViewChild property in angular parent component

Tags: angular, components, undefined, lifecycle, viewchild

child.component.ts

```
currentPage = 1;
```

parent.component.ts

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false}) child;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.child.currentPage); // throws error
  }
```

parent.component.ts

```
<app-child></app-child>
```

I tried to set a timeout but it didn't work either.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentPage' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add The Type Of Child Component :
```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: false}) child: ChildComponent
```

Comment: This always happen to me aswell. Make sure the child is not inside an ngIf and not behind a subscription if it's you have to wait to after it's set otherwise is not available.

Comment: @shAkur, if your ChildComponent is not in the Angular because you has a *ngIf="condition" -and condition is false at first, give you an error- you can solve use an if `console.log(this.child?this.child.currentPage:'not yet!')`, a fool example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xsmwyl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The reference of child component inside the parent component is indeed in a conditional: <div [hidden]="spinner"><ng-container *ngIf="results; then withResults else withoutResults"></ng-container></div>. My child reference being inside withoutResults ng template :(

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

.html

```
<app-child #ChildComponent></app-child>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild("ChildComponent", {static: true}) child:ChildComponent;
```

Comment: @angular-devkit/core              8.3.23
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.23
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.23
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.23
@schematics/angular               8.3.23

Comment: he needs to specify #ChildComponent if he wants to manipulate the DOM, but  in this case, he doesn't need this

Answer (score 1):

It works.

parent.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('child', {static: true})
  child: ChildComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.child.currentPage); // works
  }
}
```

parent.component.html

```
<app-child #child></app-child>
```

child.component.ts

```
export class ChildComponent {
    currentPage = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

specify the component name and type in the view child as follows

```
@ViewChild(HelloComponent, {static: false}) hello: HelloComponent;
```

see the example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8-viewchild-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)